# Проблемы верстки в Safari

Tags: вёрстка, safari

На apple гаджетах верстка сайтаотображается с дополнительной белой полосай справа сайта. По правилам CSS контент должен быть в центре, а некоторые блоки растянуты на всю ширину экрана и залиты разными цветами. Выходит так, что белая полоса зарезает сайт.
Скрывал и ставил по умолчанию полосу прокрутки и блоки ширина 100%.
Что это может быть и как избавится?

http://flyink.pro

что касается `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` - html5 ничего более

по иерархии, грубый примет

```
<div class"block_bg_100%">
   <div class"content_px1000">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно посмотреть исходники обязательно. Где то могла закрасться ошибка, может doctype не указан просто..

Comment: http://flyink.pro

что касается <!DOCTYPE HTML> - html5 ничего более

по иерархии, грубый примет
<div class"block_bg_100%">
   <div class"content_px1000">
   </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что знак процента в имени класса надо экранировать в css.

Answer (score 0):

Прописать min-width свойство у блока. К сведению - на разных сайтах по-разному приходится прописывать. Я вот только что парился над этой проблемой. Где-то хватает 1000px, а где-то надо 1200px